# CSS3-After-Element-Transformation not working cross browser?

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations

i think my implementation of an animated hexagon has several cross-browser-problems:
http://jsbin.com/mojavowapi/1/edit?css,output

```
.hexagon {
    position: relative;
    width: 173px;
    height: 300px;
    background-image: url(https://live.tlprod.de/temp/glas.jpg);
    background-size: auto 100%;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    transition: all 2s linear;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.hexagon:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
    background: inherit;
}

.hexLeftBox, .hexRightBox {
    overflow: hidden;
    transform: scaleY(1.6) rotate(-45deg);
    background: inherit;
    top: 27.9%;
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block; /* let the block get the width of the containing image */
    z-index: 1;
    height: 44%;
}

.hexLeft, .hexRight {
    width: auto;
    height: 100%; /* get full height of parent element, set width to aspect ratio 1:1 */
}

.hexLeftBox {
    transform: scaleY(1.6) rotate(-45deg) translate(-35.5%,-35.5%);
}

.hexRightBox {
    right: 0;
    transform: scaleY(1.6) rotate(-45deg) translate(35.5%,35.5%);
}

.hexLeftBox:after, .hexRightBox:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 142%;
    height: 142%;
    transform: rotate(45deg) scaleY(1) scaleX(1.6) translate(-50%,0%);
    transform-origin: 0 0;
    background: inherit;
    transition: all 2s linear;
}

.hexLeftBox:after {
    background-position: -7% top;
}

.hexRightBox:after {
    background-position: 107% top;
}

.hexagon:hover {
    width: 300px;
    height: 350px;
}

.hexagon:hover .hexLeftBox:after {
    background-position: -35% top;
}

.hexagon:hover .hexRightBox:after {
    background-position: 135% top;
}

.hexagon2 {
    width: 300px;
    height: 350px;
    margin-top: 40px;
}

.hexagon2 .hexLeftBox:after {
    background-position: -35% top;
}

.hexagon2 .hexRightBox:after {
    background-position: 135% top;
}
```

In this example the above hexagon changes on hover to the -same- size as the other loaded with.

- In Chrome 50 the background image of the after-elements disappear AND the aspect ratio crashes
- In IE 11 only the aspect ratio of the edges crashes
- In Firefox 46 all works fine

..but the funny thing: In all Browser the second static version with the same values as the hover is working fine.

Are there some problems known and fixable?

Comment: Nitpicking: animating width and height can be laggy sometimes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The crashed aspect ratio is a webkit-optimizing-issue.

It could be fixed only with switching to a javascript-animation with forcing the rerendering via:

```
$('body').css('display', 'table').height();
$('body').css('display', 'block');
```

And with jQuery you can do this in the progress-Parameter of the animate()-function.

Switching to a javascript-animation also eleminates the disappearing after-elements.